# Framework for Game Development on Adobe's AIR Mobile?

Tags: flash, mobile, air, adobe

I've recently tried FlashPunk for game development and it seems to be easy enough to comprehend, however, when me and a friend tested simple apps coded in it on the iPhone, it seems to be acquiring an unnecessarily large amount of memory plus dropping framerates.

Are there any other choices for game development with ActionScript 3 with frameworks that are optimized for mobile gaming?

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read, the AS3 2D Blitting engines such as FlashPunk and Flixel aren't really optimized for mobile use via Adobe AIR. That being said, I believe Quietus by Connor Ullman uses both AIR and FlashPunk and is currently available in Apple's app store with a handful of decent reviews. You could always head over to the FlashPunk forums and reach out to him, as I believe he is a regular over there.

I know you want to use a game engine for the current game you are working on, but feel free to also check out this advice from Andy Moore about maximizing AIR's performance for your mobile game. He suggests caching bitmaps and using GPU Rendering mode, both of which aren't possible with engines such as FlashPunk and Flixel.

Here is the link to the post: http://www.andymoore.ca/2012/01/how-to-improve-your-mobile-as3air-performance/

Also, I am not sure what type of paradigm the Push Button Engine implements, but perhaps it would perform better on mobile than both FlashPunk and Flixel. http://pushbuttonengine.com/

Lastly, the Corona SDK is always another cross-platform option that doesn't suffer from the same performance issues that AIR seems to be plagued by, but that is a whole other topic, and is already widely covered in existing questions on Stack Overflow.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to develop 3d or 2d games?

For 2d I could suggest Box2D for ActinoScript and Starling Framework.

Here is a nice demo and the main website.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/introducing_Starling.html

http://starling-framework.org/

Introduction to Starling http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024217.do (free ebook)

**UPDATE**

http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2012/02/mobile-gaming-gets-a-performance-boost-adobe-air-3-2-with-2d-and-3d-hardware-acceleration-announced/

Now 2D and 3D hardware accel. are expected to be released soon.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Adrian, just a question, is Box2d supposed to be used in conjunction with Starling? Starling's homepage doesn't seem to show anything about haveing a physics engine in it so I want to be sure.

Comment: Hi again. Yes you have to use both of them. I am not really an expert but I am also willing to learn more about it. So from what I know Starling is nice for animations, but you still have to use box2d for physics which not really that bad (since box2d is the best out there). Anyway here is a free book to get started http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024217.do   Will post it also in my answer.

Comment: Here is another post with great "browser based" samples. Looks impressive for me http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3371

Comment: Well I'm fine with any suggestion so long as it actually runs on iOS which is my target platform for the game.

Comment: AIR runs just fine on both iPhone and iPad so you should have no issues. Just as a hint: watch for performance issues :)

Comment: I just found out about something with regards to Starling. It seems it is based on Stage3D which is not available for the mobile AIR SDK yet. So in essence I won't be able to use it as of now since Adobe hasn't even pushed for the public release of the beta on that. :( I'd have to unmark the question as unanswered again.

Comment: check this out: http://www.flashmagazine.com/news/detail/stage3d_for_ipad_and_iphone/

Comment: The Stage3D is only available to pre-release members. It isn't available right now for the mass majority of the developers because it isn't open beta yet. At least that's what I've understood from the Starling forums.

Comment: You should check this http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2012/02/mobile-gaming-gets-a-performance-boost-adobe-air-3-2-with-2d-and-3d-hardware-acceleration-announced/